# Azure Service Bus - making sure the job is done

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I send a message to ASB, some data (a long task) will start being processed, but the processing fails miserably (someone turns off the computer/out of memory/whatever). How should I handle this situation? Like putting the queue back on the bus? Do I need to create my own monitoring/requeueing unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure ServiceBus has an internal retry policy. If a message fails to deliver, it will be send back to the queue automatically.

When creating a queue or a topic/subscription you can specify the MaxDeliveryCount.

- [QueueDescription.MaxDeliveryCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.maxdeliverycount.aspx)
- [SubscriptionDescription.MaxDeliveryCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptiondescription.maxdeliverycount.aspx)

Default value is 10. A message is automatically deadlettered after this number of deliveries.